# Compare each line in a list with a number

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a list like this:

```
cat mandi
234
562
3256
77
356
```

I want to compare each line of this list with a number `x` and then printing its output when it is bigger than a number.

I am tried this script but it has not the result that I expect.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1;

for i in {1..$mandi}
do    
    if [ "$i" -gt 10000 ];
    then
        echo "probleme"
    else
        echo "Not problem"
    fi
done
```

Comment: What is the value of `$mandi` here? And brace-expansion happens much before parameter-expansion, so whatever you are doing here won't work likely

Comment: Also, you've not mentioned if you want to store values in file and operate on the same

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
#!/bin/bash     

while read line;
do
    if (( ${line} > 1000 ));
    then
      echo "problem"
    else
      echo "good"
    fi
done < mandi
```

Comment: Don't need the `${line}`, can just use `line`.

Comment: Thank you #moviss for your help. But i want to print only when the file says "problem" not all lines.

Comment: @moviss it's not in `(())`, infact it is bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a tool like awk to achieve the same, For example

```
awk '$0>350{print $0,"-problem";next}{print $0,"-no problem"}' mandi

234 -no problem
562 -problem
3256 -problem
77 -no problem
356 -problem
```

Replace 350 with appropriate number

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps :)

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
mandi=`cat mandi` # loads to file mandi contents to a variable
mandi=($mandi) # converts to list
for i in "${mandi[@]}"
do
    if [ $i -gt 10000 ];
    then
        echo "probleme"
    else
        echo "Not problem"
fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Please use this :

```
cat mandi | while read num ;do if [ $num -gt 500 ] ;then echo "problem";else echo "no problem";fi; done;
```

result:

```
no problem
problem
problem
no problem
no problem
```